# Given functions $A(x), B(x)$ find $f(x)$ s.t. $A\big(f(x)\big)=f\big(B(x)\big)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, functional-equations

Currently, I am facing this problem:

Given two real functions $A( \vec x )$ and $B( \vec x ):\Bbb R^N\to \Bbb R$, I want to find a third real, **monotonic** function $f(x):\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that:

$$A\big(f( \vec x )\big)=f\big(B( \vec x )\big)$$

where the simplified the notation writing $f( \vec x )$ means 
$$
f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) = \big(f(x_1), f(x_2),\ldots, f(x_n)\big).
$$

I am interested in either having a formula/method for finding $f$, or even just having a proof that $f$ exists (or doesn't) under some specific conditions. Eventually, I am interested also in the solution in the case $N=1$.

Also, does this type of problem have a specific name?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Fixed! I hope now it's fun enough

Comment: you might also want to consider changing the name of your profile; the adjectives you use to characterise Schrödinger are inappropriate, IMO.

Comment: Ok, I also changed the nick to a more appropriate one. I guess the next answer I'll receive is not gonna be on the question I asked, but on the way, I use the comma. Maybe I should ask this same question on a grammar forum...

Comment: It seems too easy: if $A(x_1,x_2)=1+x_1$ and $B(x_1,x_2)=x_1+x_2$ then you are looking for $f$ such that $1+f(x_1)=f(x_1+x_2)$ which cannot be, for example if $x_2=0$. Maybe you missed some conditions? (Or did I?)

Comment: Thanks for answering, Yaakov! 

Regarding the assumptions, I am looking to see under which conditions f exists and when it doesn't. In your example, we saw that f doesn't exist, however, there are cases in which it does. E.g.

$$ A( \vec x ) = \prod x_i$$
$$ B( \vec x ) = \sum x_i$$
In this case the solution is:

$$ f( x ) = e^x $$

So, I am looking to see if there are certain conditions under which f exists (and eventually how to find it). 

I'll be happy also just to know if there is a class of similar problems and their name.

Comment: Are your functions supposed to be continuous?

Comment: More formally one can write the equation as $A\circ\vec{f}=f\circ B$, where $\vec{f}=f^{\times n}$.

Comment: *Also, does this type of problem have a specific name?*

Given two maps $A$ and $B$, trying to find an $f$ such that $A \circ f =f \circ B$ is a problem of semi-conjugacy.

Comment: Alexandre, I was checking if I could add some extra assumptions which are not too stringent.

Assuming they all are continuous is acceptable.  Regarding f, we can also assume it to be derivable.

Answer (score 5):

Existence of such $f$ is a very strong condition on $A$ and $B$ which is called semi-conjugacy. Of course, for generic $A$ and $B$ function $f$ does not exist. Suppose for simplicity that $N=1$. Then it is clear that the image of any fixed point of $B$ under $f$ is a fixed point of $A$. Furthermore, when $N=1$, your equation implies that
$$A^n\circ f=f\circ B^n$$ 
where $A^n$ means the $n$-th iterate. This implies that periodic points of $B$ are mapped to periodic points of $A$ of the same period. So we have some very complicated relation between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Alexandre, thank you very much!

I think I need to study a little more the theory of topological conjugacy, as there are some points that I don't fully understand.

By adding slightly more stringent conditions (i.e. A() and B() continuous and f derivable) is it possible to find a solution to the problem? Otherwise, what are the typical hypotheses to solve it? (if they exist)

Eventually, could you suggest me a book or article that could help me in understanding better how to solve the problem?

Again, thanks a lot!